# C# - Not hitting the desired if

Tags: c#

This may seem like a fairly basic question, but I'm pretty new to c# and have only had 3 months of the job training and no formal programming study prior, so again, sorry if this seems quite basic.

I have a program that is not hitting the desired if.
Regardless of a bad request sent back as the response, the program treats it as though it's all ok.
Any suggestions?

The code is attached; it will only hit 1st regardless of response. Changing to else creates errors.
Changing != to == just creates a loop.

```
if (response != null && ((response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)))
{
  Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
  Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
  Conn.Close();
  Conn.ClearPool();
  Conn.Dispose();
  dr1.Close();
  GetToken();
}

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
  Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
  Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
  Conn.Close();
  Conn.ClearPool();
  Conn.Dispose();
  dr1.Close();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
  exit_state();
}
```

Comment: Can you debug it and check the actual value of response.StatusCode during runtime. Sounds like it is no bad request otherwise it should definitely hit or throw an exception, if the response is null.

Comment: Is this code inside of a try.. catch statement?

Comment: `response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK`  will still return `true` when `response.StatusCode` is `BadRequest`. So still first if block will execute. A simple solution will be to move the second `if` block to the top

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is unclear, I believe you should remove `response != null` and use an `else if` statement:

```cs
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                    Conn.Close();
                    Conn.ClearPool();
                    Conn.Dispose();
                    dr1.Close();
                    GetToken();
                }
                else if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                    Conn.Close();
                    Conn.ClearPool();
                    Conn.Dispose();
                    dr1.Close();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
                    exit_state();
                }
```

Comment: Wrong answer, `response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK`  will still return `true` when `response.StatusCode` is `BadRequest`. So still first if block will execute. A simple solution will be to move the second `if` block to the top

Comment: As in, just swap them around?

Comment: Yes, that would work @DrewStory

Comment: @Satpal yeah I had realized that and I deleted the question for a quick second. You should probably create your own answer for the sake of this site.

Comment: @Rojo, It's fine mate. Please make the necessary changes to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the response is not `null` and the status code is something other than `OK`, the first if statement condition is true, so even if a `BadRequest` comes, it also goes to first if statement. If there is something here that loops the code `infinitely`, it cannot reach the second if statement.

```
            if (response != null && response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.BadRequest && ((response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                Conn.Close();
                Conn.ClearPool();
                Conn.Dispose();
                dr1.Close();
                GetToken();
            }

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                Console.WriteLine(statusCode);
                Conn.Close();
                Conn.ClearPool();
                Conn.Dispose();
                dr1.Close();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
                exit_state();
            }
```

Comment: The program gets a BadRequest back, but treats it as ok, then goes to get a new API key, and this becomes a loop.

Comment: I updated your code altough it's not a nice approach, i think it will work as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second if statement to:

```
 if (response != null && (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest))
```